# How to transpile JavaScript Using Babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I know that setting up inline javascript transpile using babel

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
     // your es6 code
</script>
```

but is it possible to give string version of the es6 code into babel and get the transpiled version as a string?

```
var normal_jacascript = babel.convert(es6_code);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure.

Here is a really simple example, if you notice the code is using `const` and some React JSX, and then I compile to es2015/React, it changes to a `var`, and `React.createElement` for the JSX.

You can of course decide what presets to use too.

```js
var ret = Babel.transform("const x = 2; const b = <b/>;", {
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
});

console.log(ret.code);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
```